# Sforce.console.closeTab() not working from Visualforce Page embedded in Lightning page

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience

I have embedded a visual force page in a lightning component,  which has a functionality to close the current console tab: I have embedded the VF page using using an iframe.

**Visualforce Page Code:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false">
  <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/47.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var closePage = function (result) {
            //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can close it
                var currentTabId = result.id;

        sforce.console.closeTab(currentTabId);

        };


function closeCurrentTab(){
    alert(1);
    sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(closePage);
}

</script>

<button onclick="closeCurrentTab();" value="closeTab">Close Tab</button>
```

**Lightning Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"  access="global" >

<iframe id="commHolder" 
                    src="/apex/TestEmbedLightningConsoleAPI"            
            ></iframe>
</aura:component>
```

**And it render as :**

[image]

As click the Close button I am getting below error:

***SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "Sfdc" on cross-origin object

```
handleOnload https://test--item.cs83.my.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/iframeinterface.js:1
onload https://test--item.cs83.my.salesforce.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/crossDomainProxy.html#xdomain_name=s:getEnclosingPrimaryTabId&xdomain_targetFrame=s:sfdc-console&xdomain_txnId=s:0&xdomain_pathToOriginProxy=s:https://test--item.cs83.visual.force.com/support/console/xdomain/30.0/crossDomainProxy.html&xdomain_originFrame=s:&version=s:47.0:4***
```

[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?

***The another fact is,  as I embed this page in a Appbuilder page by dragging the visualforce page, The functionality is working and the current tab is closing***

**Why this strange behavior is happening ?**

Any help would be appreciated, as an urgent item.